# Parameters in RedirectToAction don't passed down

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass down parameters to my Action.
There are several parameters that I need to pass down.
When debugging, I found that the simple types of parameters got their values, whereas my own class parameters is null.

```
return RedirectToAction("Histories", new {MyUser = user, sortOrder = "name_desc" });
```

And here is the Action method:

```
   public ActionResult Histories(ApplicationUser MyUser, string sortOrder, int? page)
```

I did a research and found , it seems that only objects which can be serialized can be passed down.

So I simply added an annotation [Serializable] on my ApplicationUser class, and it doesn't work.

So I'm wondering what's the best practice to pass down my objects？

I certainly know I can put the MyUser into Session["CurrentUser"], but I just don't like this old fashion.

Thank you.

Comment: `TempData["CurrentUser"]` is the most common way, but you can also look into a more complex setup with Server.TransferRequest

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409899/pass-complex-object-with-redirect-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: hi @OleksiiAza that post uses the same thing TempData[] to pass objects

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed int? page value, it should be like this

```
return RedirectToAction("Histories", new {MyUser = user, 
           sortOrder = "name_desc", 
           page =1 });
```

or you need to use default parameter value like this

```
public ActionResult Histories(ApplicationUser MyUser,
     string sortOrder, 
     int? page = 1)
```

Comment: hi, the page parameter is nullable, so that's okay. I want to know how to pass MyUser.