# Sending parameters to ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In my page I have a datatable. What I want is to change the data on table by from options on tree menu which are links. Basically, each item on tree menu will trigger the Stored Procedure with different parameters.

So far I tried to send the parameter like

```
<a href="@Url.Action("InboxListByType", "Folder", new { DocumentTypeId = 3 })">e-TCGB</a>
```

But it is not working. I'm stuck so bad.

This is the ActionResult

```
public ActionResult InboxListByType(FormCollection coll, int DocumentTypeId)
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    int CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(identity.FindFirst("CompanyId").Value);

    int Draw = Convert.ToInt32(coll["draw"]);
    int RowStart = Convert.ToInt32(coll["start"]);
    int RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(coll["length"]);
    int TotalRows = 0;
    DataSet ds = DocumentDB.Document_List_Inbox(CompanyId, RowStart, RowCount, DocumentTypeId, out TotalRows);

    string DatatableJson = Utility.DatatableToJson(ds.Tables[0]);

    return Content("{ \"draw\": " + Draw + ", \"recordsTotal\" :" + TotalRows + " , \"recordsFiltered\": " + TotalRows + ", \"data\": " + DatatableJson + " } ");
}
```

One of the problems is FormCollection `coll` element is coming in as `null`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your making a GET, not a POST so `FormCollection` will always be `null`.  If you want to send values for `draw`, `start` etc, then you need to add query string or route values - `new { DocumentTypeId = 3, Draw = someValue }` and add those parameters to the method

Comment: Would changing the ActionResult to POST work too?

Comment: No, Because its a link (which does a redirect to a GET method), not a form.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409899/pass-complex-object-with-redirect-in-asp-net-mvc may it would help

Comment: What are you trying to return?

Comment: I'm returning table data